# Changing the RegExp flags

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype, flags

So basically I wrote myself this function so as to be able to count the number of occurances of a Substring in a String:

```
String.prototype.numberOf = function(needle) {
  var num = 0,
      lastIndex = 0;
  if(typeof needle === "string" || needle instanceof String) {
    while((lastIndex = this.indexOf(needle, lastIndex) + 1) > 0)
      {num++;} return num;
  } else if(needle instanceof RegExp) {
    // needle.global = true;
    return this.match(needle).length;
  } return 0;
};
```

The method itself performs rather well and both the RegExp and String based searches are quite comparable as to the execution time (both ~2ms on the entire vast Ray Bradbury's "451 Fahrenheit" searching for all the "the"s).

What sort of bothers me, though, is the impossibility of changing the flag of the supplied RegExp instance. There is no point in calling *String.prototype.match* in this function without the global flag of the supplied Regular Expression set to true, as it would only note the first occurance then. You could certainly set the flag manually on each RegExp passed to the function, I'd however prefer being able to clone and then manipulate the supplied Regular Expression's flags.

Astonishingly enough, I'm not permitted to do so as the *RegExp.prototype.global* flag (more precisely all flags) appear to be read-only. Thence the commented-out line 8.

So my question is: **Is there a *nice* way of changing the flags of a RegExp object?**

I don't really wanna do stuff like this:

```
if(!expression.global)
  expression = eval(expression.toString() + "g");
```

Some implementations might not event support the *RegExp.prototype.toString* and simply inherit it from the *Object.prototype*, or it could be a different formatting entirely. And it just seems as a bad coding practice to begin with.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, your current code does not work correctly when `needle` is a regex which does not match. i.e. The following line:

```js
return this.match(needle).length;
```

The `match` method returns `null` when there is no match. A JavaScript error is then generated when the `length` property of `null` is (unsuccessfully) accessed. This is easily fixed like so:

```js
var m = this.match(needle);
return m ? m.length : 0;
```

Now to the problem at hand. You are correct when you say that `global`, `ignoreCase` and `multiline` are read only properties. The only option is to create a new RegExp. This is easily done since the regex source string is stored in the `re.source` property. Here is a tested modified version of your function which corrects the problem above and creates a new RegExp object when `needle` does not already have its `global` flag set:

```js
String.prototype.numberOf = function(needle) {
    var num = 0,
    lastIndex = 0;
    if (typeof needle === "string" || needle instanceof String) {
        while((lastIndex = this.indexOf(needle, lastIndex) + 1) > 0)
            {num++;} return num;
    } else if(needle instanceof RegExp) {
        if (!needle.global) {
            // If global flag not set, create new one.
            var flags = "g";
            if (needle.ignoreCase) flags += "i";
            if (needle.multiline) flags += "m";
            needle = RegExp(needle.source, flags);
        }
        var m = this.match(needle);
        return m ? m.length : 0;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency. I like the solution, it is maybe safer not to extend the RegExp prototype with a flags function (as suggested above).

Comment: Better yet, use `myRegex.test(str)` if that's all you care about. It's both shorter and faster.

Comment: Not quite, I'm trying to count all the occurances. :-)

Answer (score 15):

```
var globalRegex = new RegExp(needle.source, "g");
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H7YD7/)** **EDIT**: The m was only for the sake of demonstrating that you can set multiple modifiers

```
var regex = /find/;
var other = new RegExp(regex.source, "gm");
alert(other.global);
alert(other.multiline);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
r = new Regexp(r.source, r.flags + (r.global ? "" : "g"));
```

Comment: Use a note, the () around `r.global ? "" : "g"` is necessary because the conditional operator has a lower precedence than addition. That tripped me up so be careful.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't much you can do but I highly recommend you avoid using `eval`. You can extend the RegExp prototype to help you out.

```
RegExp.prototype.flags = function () {
    return (this.ignoreCase ? "i" : "")
        + (this.multiline ? "m" : "")
        + (this.global ? "g" : "");
};

var reg1 = /AAA/i;
var reg2 = new RegExp(reg1.source, reg1.flags() + 'g');
```

Comment: I figured out the .source part just a few moments ago. I, however, completely forgot about the fact that the flags aren't a part of the source. :)  I think I will incorporate the idea. Thanks ;)