# Combination of regex "gi" modifiers doesn't work for single words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple script to match series episode codes, like **S01E02** or **s09e11**. The idea is to find all of the episode codes in the provided text and create an array of objects, containing all episodes found.

I first use `match()` to get the array of all matched codes, then I loop through the codes to extract the season and episode number.

Problem is, when I use the same regex patter with `/gi` modifiers both for finding all matches, and extracting the episode details, I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` (see the Console output).

**Case 1 (failing)** -- **[fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/qg6o7tdf/2/)**

```
var episodePatternGI = /s(\d{1,2})e(\d{1,2})/gi;
var matches = 'S3E1 hehehe bla s09e12'.match(episodePatternGI);
var episodes = [];

matches.forEach(function(val) {
    var ep = episodePatternGI.exec(val);
    episodes.push({
    s: ep[1],
    e: ep[2]
  });
});

console.log(episodes);
```

**Case 2 (working)** -- **[fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/m8e5pj68/1/)**

```
var episodePatternGI = /s(\d{1,2})e(\d{1,2})/gi;
var matches = 'S3E1 hehehe bla s09e12'.match(episodePatternGI);
var episodes = [];

var episodePatternI = /s(\d{1,2})e(\d{1,2})/i; // g modifier removed

matches.forEach(function(val) {
    var ep = episodePatternI.exec(val); // New pattern applied
    episodes.push({
    s: ep[1],
    e: ep[2]
  });
});

console.log(episodes);
```

As you can see, in the second case I use the same pattern, but the `g` modifier is removed.

**Why doesn't the first case work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `lastIndex` is not resetted automatically, so when you call `exec` for the second match, it won't start looking at the beginning of the string, and thus it won't match.

You can reset `lastIndex` manually by setting it to `0`:

```
var episodePatternGI = /s(\d{1,2})e(\d{1,2})/gi;
var matches = 'S3E1 hehehe bla s09e12'.match(episodePatternGI);
var episodes = matches.map(function(val) {
  episodePatternGI.lastIndex = 0;
  var ep = episodePatternGI.exec(val);
  return {
    s: ep[1],
    e: ep[2]
  };
});
console.log(episodes);
```

Calling `exec` repeatedly until reaching the end of the string (a 2nd call should be enough), as shown in [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35830139/1529630), will reset `lastIndex` too.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Aww you beat me to the answer. I was just about to submit

Comment: An even better answer though, would be to actually *use* the `lastIndex` to your advantage and just loop through `exec()` until it returns null. Because currently the regex is being used twice as much as it needs to be. Skip the matches array portion.

Comment: There is no need to call both match and exec and it can be error prone as well

Comment: True. I just wanted to show what was the problem with OP's approach, and the minimal way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `regexp.exec` in a loop to grab the captured group while using `g` flag:

```
var episodePatternGI = /s(\d{1,2})e(\d{1,2})/gi;
var str = 'S3E1 hehehe bla s09e12';
var episodes = [];

var m;
while ((m = episodePatternGI.exec(str)) !== null) {
    episodes.push({
        s: m[1],
        e: m[2]
      });
}

console.log(episodes);
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qg6o7tdf/5/)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS8tD7/2) (check *code generator* in this link)

Comment: OK, I see. Basically I need to manually keep track of `exec()` index during each iteration. Kinda annoying ;) Thanks!

Comment: The thing I don't get, though, is that in my code I am looping through an array of codes, and I'm extracting season and episode from each code **separately**. Yet, the `exec()` index is somehow global? The solution with `while` is a bit different, more concise. The `forEach` one - not working -  is bothering me.

Comment: Actually that's not really needed in this case, see updated answer now.

Comment: This is the best answer. MUCH cleaner and faster than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in multiple flags to a RegExp in JS, you can also do something like this:

```
var episodePatternGI = /s(\d{1,2})e(\d{1,2})/;
var other = new RegExp(episodePatternGI.source, "gi");
```

here is a relevant thread: [Changing the RegExp flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835469/changing-the-regexp-flags)